# PowerShellの実行セキュリティポリシー設定方法

Tags: powershell

Windows7 64bit環境です。
Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 ファイルを用意して、 Import-Module をしています。

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

を管理者権限で実行して、スタートメニューから PowerShell を起動したときに、モジュールが読み込み済みの状態になりました。

そしてこのモジュールを使う setting.ps1 ファイルを作成し

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "powershell.exe ～\setting.ps1",1
```

という ps1 ファイルをキックする VBS ファイルを作成し、
エクスプローラーから実行すると正常に動作することを確認しました。

別のアプリに外部ファイルを実行する機能があり、このVBSを呼び出すようにしたのですが、

```
スクリプトの実行がシステムで無効になっているため、ファイル ～\マイ ドキュメント\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 を読み込めません。詳細については、「get-help about_signing」と入力してヘルプを参照してください。
発生場所 行:1 文字:2
+ . <<<<  '～\マイ ドキュメント\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1'
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) []、PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

というエラーになってしまいます。
PowerShell 単体が起動するようにして、 Get-ExecutionPolicy を確認してみましたが、
Restricted でした。

実行ポリシーはユーザー毎に管理なのでしょうか？
ただ、上記の別のアプリも同じユーザーで起動しています。

マシン全体、または該当ユーザーで PowerShell を起動したときに、共通したポリシーが適用されるようにするにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4):

Twitterで教えて頂きました。
32bit、64bitで設定が異なるそうです。

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy -List
```

でポリシーの一覧が確認できるのですが、
スタートメニューから起動した PowerShell と PowerShell(x86) で比べてみたところ、
x86の方では設定が反映されていませんでした。

x86側でも

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

を実行して解決。
質問にあった「別のアプリ」が32bit版だったため、このような動きになっていたようです。